# How would one change the value inside a hash table in Java based on the time that has elapsed?

Tags: java, timer, distributed-system, heartbeat

I'm trying to simulate an distributed file system and I'm having a little trouble simulating how a heartbeat works. I have one name node that stores file meta data, and data nodes that actually store the file blocks. Periodically (like every 3 seconds), I send a message from the data node to the name node telling the name node that it is alive.

Currently, I have a HashTable in the name node that stores as the key the data node name (String) and as the value a boolean that tells me if the Data Node is still alive or not. If I receive a message from the Data Node, the value in the hash table gets switched to true. The part I'm having difficulties with is how would I switch the value back to false if I don't receive a message from the Data Node in say 10 seconds?

The only thing I could think of is timestamping each heartbeat and placing each timestamp in another hashtable that contains the data node name and a timestamp. Then write a function that compares the current time to each of the timestamps in the hashtable and change any data node with timestamp from more than 10 seconds ago to false in the boolean hash table. Then put that function in an infinite while loop. What would be a better way to approach something like this?

Comment: What do you do with this "liveness" information? Can't you just use the table with the timestamps - if the timestamp is older than 10 seconds consider the node dead.

Answer (score 1):

You change the map from `Map<String, Boolean>` to `Map<String, Instant>`, so it stores the last heartbeat time, instead of just an "is alive" boolean.

Then you write a `boolean isAlive(String name)` method that will lookup the map entry. If entry is found and the stored `Instant` is less than 10 seconds in the past, you return `true`, otherwise you return `false`.

There is no need to keep the `Map` up-to-date. You simply *encapsulate* the map with that method, to *interpret* the map value "live" when queried.